# Multiple eager loading with multiple conditions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.7 version.

I would like to use multiple eager loading with where clauses.

I have laravel simplified.

```
$query = Employee::with(['User','Company','Client'])
                  ->select(*)->whereRaw("(User.id <> 0 and Company.name LIKE %A%) OR Client.id <> 0)")
```

I am using eager loading to avoid JOIN statement.

But the problem is the error message says User.id is unknown column in where clause.

I believe the other two would be unknown columns as well.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a bit uggly, but you can use a closure:

```
$query = Employee::with('User', function ($inner) {
    $inner->where('id', '!=', 0);
})->with(['Company', 'Client'])
->where(function (Builder $sub) use($companyName) {
    $sub->where('Company.name', 'like', $companyName)
        ->orWhere('Client.id', '!=', 0);
})->get();
```

This will retrieve:

```
employees where (user.id != 0 AND (company.name LIKE :companyName OR client.id != 0))
```

In order to modify the order of those constraints you'll need to move the closure and constraints according to your requirements, but for what I understood this should do it.